# Java: Generics input type compatibility

Tags: java, generics

I am a java beginner and I am reading the book "Java a beginner's guide" and the topic of generics.The author created the following generic class:

```
// In this version of NumericFns, the type argument
// for T must be either Number, or a class derived
// from Number.
class NumericFns<T extends Number> {
    T num;
    // Pass the constructor a reference to
    // a numeric object.
    NumericFns(T n) {
        num = n;
    }
```

In this case, the type argument
must be either Number or
a subclass of Number.

```
    // Return the reciprocal.
    double reciprocal() {
        return 1 / num.doubleValue();
    }
    // Return the fractional component.
    double fraction() {
        return num.doubleValue() - num.intValue();
    }
    // ...
}
```

and the author says that if we add a new method that checks the absolute value of numerical value stored in two generic objects like following:

```
// This won't work!
// Determine if the absolute values of two objects are the same.
boolean absEqual(NumericFns<T> ob) {
    if(Math.abs(num.doubleValue()) ==
            Math.abs(ob.num.doubleValue()) return true;
    return false;
}
```

And the explanation written with it is:

> Here, the standard method Math.abs( ) is used to obtain the absolute value of each number,
>       and then the values are compared. The trouble with this attempt is that it will work only with
>       other NumericFns objects whose type is the same as the invoking object. For example, if the
>       invoking object is of type `NumericFns<Integer>`, then the parameter ob must also be of type
>       `NumericFns<Integer>`. It can’t be used to compare an object of type `NumericFns<Double>`,
>       for example. Therefore, this approach does not yield a general (i.e., generic) solution.

I am not able to understand why it will not work properly for all different types.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `T` in `absEqual(NumericFns<T> ob)` is the same `T` as the one in the constructor if that method is in the same class. That's why if using different `NumericFns` where `T` is once a `Integer` and once a `Double`, you get:

```
error: incompatible types: NumericFns<Double> cannot be converted to NumericFns<Integer>
```

Instead you could use:

```
// This will work!
// Determine if the absolute values of two objects are the same.
boolean absEqual(NumericFns<? extends Number> ob) {
    if( Math.abs(num.doubleValue()) ==
            Math.abs(ob.num.doubleValue()) ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I got it now, Thanks.